# Use values in vector to add rows in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a vector of names:

```
nums = 1:5
names = paste("name_", nums, sep="")
```

And a data frame where col1 contains a subset of the values listed in names:

```
Name    Count
name_1  14
name_3  2
name_5  11
```

I would like to use the vector of names to add rows to the data frame for names that are currently missing from the data frame, so that the final product looks like this:

```
Name    Count
name_1  14
name_2  0
name_3  2
name_4  0
name_5  11
```

I've come across some other variations of this question, but can't seem to find a solution that matches my scenario. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `complete`

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df1, Name = names, fill = list(Count = 0))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Name   Count
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 name_1    14
#2 name_2     0
#3 name_3     2
#4 name_4     0
#5 name_5    11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("name_1", "name_3", "name_5"), Count = c(14L, 
2L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data.frame(names, Count = pmax(df1$Count[match(names, df1$Name)], 0, na.rm = TRUE))
#   names Count
#1 name_1    14
#2 name_2     0
#3 name_3     2
#4 name_4     0
#5 name_5    11
```

Comment: Huh, so R *does* have a built-in coalesce function, it's just hidden in a max function. Never would have guessed

Answer (score 3):

You can merge and then replace the NAs resulting from non-matches with 0

```
out <- merge(df, data.frame(Name = names), all = TRUE)
out$Count <- with(out, replace(Count, is.na(Count), 0))

out
#     Name Count
# 1 name_1    14
# 2 name_2     0
# 3 name_3     2
# 4 name_4     0
# 5 name_5    11
```